# Django ORM: Joining a table to itself

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a table with cryptocurrency prices:

```
id | price  | pair_id | exchange_id | date
---+--------+---------+-------------+---------------------------
 1 | 8232.7 |       1 |           1 | 2018-02-09 09:31:00.160837
 2 | 8523.8 |       1 |           2 | 2018-02-09 09:31:01.353998
 3 | 240.45 |       2 |           1 | 2018-02-09 09:31:02.524333
```

I want to get the latest prices of a single pair from different exchanges. In raw SQL, I do it like this:

```
SELECT b.price, b.date, k.price, k.date, AVG((b.price + k.price) / 2)
FROM converter_price b JOIN converter_price k 
WHERE b.exchange_id=1 AND k.exchange_id=2 AND b.pair_id=1 AND k.pair_id=1
ORDER BY b.date DESC, k.date DESC LIMIT 1;

8320.1|2018-02-09 11:23:00.369810|8318.2|2018-02-09 11:23:06.467424|8245.05199328066
```

How to do such query in the Django ORM?

EDIT: Adding models.py. I understand that it's quite likely that I'll need to update it.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Pair(models.Model):
    identifier = models.CharField('Pair identifier', max_length=6)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.identifier


class Exchange(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Exchange name', max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Price(models.Model):
    pair = models.ForeignKey(Pair, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exchange = models.ForeignKey(Exchange, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}: {} ({})'.format(
            self.date, self.pair, self.price, self.exchange)
```

EDIT2: To clarify what I'm really after.

I want the latest price with pair_id=1 and exchange_id=1, and the latest price with pair_id=1 and exchange_id=2. With a single query, and without any subsequent processing in Python - of course I can get Price.objects.all() and then search for it myself, but that's not the right way to use the ORM.

The way to do this with raw SQL is joining the table to itself. Showing how to join a table to itself using the Django ORM would (probably) answer the question.

Comment: Please add your `models.py`.

Comment: Can't understand what you are saying.

Comment: @Ted Moravec I updated the answer,